# Checkbox is missing in related products in magento

Tags: php, magento, checkbox, magento-1.7

I'm using magento C.E 1.7. My product view page is coming from easytabs since I'm using easy tabs plugin. Also related products are viewing from easytabs.

Problem is, Most of the products not having checkbox in related products list. I checked their stock availability, required options etc in admin. No problem with product settings. My code is below

```
<div class="box-collateral box-description">
<?php if($this->getItems()->getSize()): ?>
        <p class="test"><strong><?php echo $this->__('Check items to add to the cart or') ?>&nbsp;<a href="#" onclick="selectAllRelated(this);return false;"><?php echo $this->__('select all') ?></a></strong></p>
        <ol class="tabsrelated">
        <?php foreach($this->getItems() as $_item): ?>
            <li <?php if($_item->isComposite() || !$_item->isSaleable()): ?> class="super-products"<?php endif; ?> id="tabsheight">
                <div class="product-images">
                <?php if(!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()): ?>
                    <span class="checkbox-container">
                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()): ?>
                        <input type="checkbox" class="related-checkbox left" id="related-checkbox<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" name="related_products[]" value="<?php echo $_item->getId() ?>" />
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    </span>
                <?php else: ?>
                    <span class="checkbox-container">&nbsp;</span>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_item, 'thumbnail')->resize(150) ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?>" width="150" height="150" /></a>
                </div>
                <div class="product-details">
                    <a href="<?php echo $_item->getProductUrl() ?>"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                    <div style="clear:both;">
                        <div class="related-price">
                            <?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_item, true) ?>
                        </div>
                        <div class="related-shipping" style="line-height:25.5px">&nbsp;
                        + Free Shipping
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <?php if ($this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow()) : ?>
                    <div>
                        <a href="<?php echo $this->getAddToWishlistUrl($_item) ?>" class="link-cart"><?php echo $this->__('Add to Wishlist') ?></a>
                    </div>
                    <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </li>
        <?php endforeach ?>
        </ol>
```

How to view all related products with checkbox? Can anyone help here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do your products have custom options? If so, I dont think a checkbox will be shown as you must in that case go to the product and select those custom options and are not able to directly select it in the related products area.

Comment: Yes, You are Right. Products have custom options as required field. That is why such products did not come up with checkbox. Thank You!